# Not getting the correct path after uploading a file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

I am uploading a file on server and storing the its path in database in codeigniter, however i am after the upload i am not getting the correct path

The code that i have used is

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'doc|docx|pdf';
$config['max_size']             = 100;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

$image_path = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
```

I wish to save the path that i am getting in **$image_path** inside database.

> Now the path that i get is something like this
>
> ```
> /home/litehepn/public_html/project_name/uploads/xyz.docx
> ```
>
> But the path that i want is
>
> ```
> project_name/uploads/xyz.docx
> ```

Can anyone please tell how to get the correct path

Comment: As `project_name` & `uploads` both are known, why not you saving `project_name/uploads/xyz.docx` this directly in DB? (because you are getting `xyz.docx` file name after upload)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct path. Because you have stored your files inside that home directory.  But You can use `chop($url,"/home/litehepn/public_html/");` for getting it.

Comment: you should write $url = "/home/litehepn/public_html/project_name/uploads/xyz.docx"; Then $new_url = chop($url,"/home/litehepn/public_html/");